# How to set up SNMP in Ubuntu server 18.04 to report access point activity to Zabbix dashboard?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, snmp, zabbix

I really need assistance in setting up SNMP to work with Zabbix on my dashboard.
I have set up an Ubuntu 18.04 Zabbix server and have added over 18 agents. All virtual machines with Zabbix agents and they are working great!

Now I have gotten to the point where I need to have the AP's set up for Zabbix. 
I have followed the instructions and did the following so far:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snmp snmp-mibs-downloader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snmpd
```

I opened `sudo nano /etc/snmp/snmp.conf` and commented the following line:

```
#mibs :
```

Then I went into the configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

And from there I made changes to the following lines:

```
Listen for connections from the local system only
agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161  <--- commented this part.
Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 and IPv6)
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161  <--remove the comment from this line to make it work.
```

Then I set up the Zabbix dashboard side. I will attach pictures of the set-up.

1st zabbix dashboard menu:

[image: 1st zabbix dashboard menu]

2nd dashboard set-up menu:

[image: 2nd dashboard set-up menu]

I get the following error:

[image: This is a picture of the error I receive.]

I will also attach picture that shows my meraki access point set-up.

Meraki AP SNMP set-up:

[image: Meraki AP SNMP set-up.]

Lastly, I will add a picture that shows the Linux Zabbix server terminal set up on that config file.

Linux Zabbix Server:

[image: Linux Zabbix Server]

I am stumped and cannot figure out why Zabbix still throwing out that error.

I have gone thru the Zabbix documentation but cannot find a solution to my problem.

Comment: a) It looks like you are trying to poll SNMP devices - this means that there is no need to configure snmpd on the Zabbix server. b) You said you "followed the instructions" - which instructions? c) Please include the error message as text in your question. d) Try to poll the device with `snmpget` from the Zabbix server - if that does not work, no point in trying with Zabbix.

Comment: @Richlv I appreciate the response, anyways you can give me an example on how to use the snmpget? I am still a noob at linux and trying to figure this all out.

Comment: Usage of `snmpget` is a bit of an offtopic for this question, but see http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmpget.html for detail.

Answer (score 0):

Take these 2 steps :

1- install and config snmpd

2- install MIBs and config ***snmp*** conf file (not snmpd file)

Step 1:
Run the following commands in the terminal:

**Update all packages**: sudo apt-get update

**Install SNMP**: sudo apt-get install snmpd

**Edit snmpd.conf with text editor of your choice, we will be using nano**: sudo nano /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

**It should look like this**:

"#Listen for connections from the local system only"

"#agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161"

"Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6"

"agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161"

**(#'s are important!!! the first two should have # and the last two should not!)**

**Configure rocommunity**: rocommunity **public** (or whatever you like to use)

**save and exit (ctrl+x , Yes , Enter)**

**Restart the SNMPD service**: sudo service snmpd restart

Step 2:

sudo apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader

sudo download-mibs

To have the new MIBs recognized by net-snmp, edit /etc/snmp/**snmp.conf** file as follows:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/snmp/snmp.conf

mibs +ALL

$
```

to test run :

snmptranslate -Tp on Terminal and youll get the MIB Trees

Go back to Zabbix you see it's working now !!!! :)